# How to show that $V=\oplus_{\chi\in Hom(G, \mathbb{C}^{\times})} V^{\chi}$?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group and $Hom(G, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ be the set of all characters of $G$. For $\chi: G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $(\pi, V)$ a representation of $G$, let
$$
V^{\chi} = \{v\in V: \pi(g)v = \chi(g)v\}.
$$

How to show that $V=\oplus_{\chi\in Hom(G, \mathbb{C}^{\times})} V^{\chi}$?

Since $G$ is cyclic group, $Hom(G, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ is cyclic. Suppose that $|G|=n$. Then $|Hom(G, \mathbb{C}^{\times})|=n$. We may assume that $Hom(G, \mathbb{C}^{\times}) = \{\chi_1, \ldots, \chi_n\}$.

In order to show that $V=\oplus_{\chi\in Hom(G, \mathbb{C}^{\times})} V^{\chi}$, we have to show that each $v \in V$ can be written as a sum $v_1 + \ldots + v_n$, $v_i \in V^{\chi_i}$ and $V^{\chi_i} \cap V^{\chi_j} =\{0\}$ if $i \ne j$. By the definition of $V^\chi$, it is easy to see that $V^{\chi_i} \cap V^{\chi_j} =\{0\}$ if $i \ne j$.

But how to show that each $v \in V$ can be written as a sum $v_1 + \ldots + v_n$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a nice proof outlined in Diamond and Shurman's book, "A first course in modular forms", ex. 4.3.4. It goes this way: for all $\chi\in\hom (G,\mathbb C^*)$ define the linear operator $p_{\chi}\colon V\to V$ as $p_{\chi}=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g}\chi^{-1}(g)\pi(g)$. Now one proves several simple facts:

1) $p_{\chi}(V)\subseteq V^{\chi}$ and $p_{\chi}$ is the identity on $V^{\chi}$.

2) $p_{\chi}^2=p_{\chi}$, so $\chi$ is a projection onto $V^{\chi}$.

3) $\sum_{\chi}p_{\chi}$ is the identity map $V\to V$, thanks to orthogonality relations. This tells us that the spaces $V^{\chi}$ span $V$.

4) For $\chi\neq\chi'$ one has $p_{\chi}\circ p_{\chi'}=0$, again by orthogonality relations. Therefore the $V^{\chi}$'s are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: thank you very much. But 3) and 4) are not the same as the [orthogonality relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Orthogonality_relations).

Comment: Actually they are, because since $G$ is abelian, then two elements are conjugate iff they coincide, so orthogonality relations just tell you that $\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)=|G|$ iff $\chi$ is the trivial character, otherwise it's $0$. By duality, you also have that $\sum_{\chi\in \widehat{G}}\chi(g)=|G|$ iff $g=1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: thank you very much. Now I understand. We have $\sum_{\chi} p_{\chi}(v) = \sum_{\chi} \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi^{-1}(g) \pi(g) (v) = \frac{1}{|G|}  \sum_{g \in G} \left(  \sum_{\chi } \chi^{-1}(g)\right) \pi(g) (v) = \frac{1}{|G|} |G| \pi(1) (v) = \pi(1) (v) = v$.

Comment: $p_{\chi'} \circ p_{\chi}(v) = \frac{1}{|G|^2}\sum_{g' \in G}  \chi'^{-1}(g') \pi(g')\left( \sum_{g \in G} \chi^{-1}(g) \pi(g)(v) \right) = \frac{1}{|G|^2}\sum_{g' \in G} \chi'^{-1}(g') \left(  \sum_{g \in G} \chi^{-1}(g) \pi(g' g)(v) \right) = \frac{1}{|G|^2}\left( \sum_{g' \in G} \chi'^{-1}(g') \chi^{-1}(g'^{-1}) \right) \left(  \sum_{g_1 \in G} \chi^{-1}(g_1) \pi(g_1)(v) \right) = 0$ since $\chi \neq \chi'$.

Comment: I have a question about the above computations. One factor last term of the above equation is $\sum_{g' \in G} \chi'^{-1} (g') \chi^{-1} (g'^{-1}) = \sum_{g\in G} \chi'^{-1}(g) \chi(g) \quad (1)$. We know that $\chi \neq \chi'$. But we don't know that if $\chi'^{-1} \neq \chi$. Could we conclude that $(1)=0$? Thank you very much.

Comment: So the correct way to see it is: $p_{\chi}p_{\chi'}=\frac{1}{|G|^2}(\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)^{-1}\pi(g))(\sum_{h\in G}\chi'(h)^{-1}\pi(h))=\frac{1}{|G|^2}\sum_{x\in G}\pi(x)\sum_{gh=x}\chi(g)^{-1}\chi'(h)^{-1}$.Now write $h^{-1}=g/x$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: thank you very much. But this is similar as my computations. $\sum_{gh=x}\chi(g)^{-1}\chi'(h)^{-1} = \sum_{gh=x}\chi(g)^{-1}\chi'(g/x) = \chi(x)^{-1} \sum_{gh=x} \chi(g)^{-1} \chi'(g)$. We still don't know $\chi^{-1} \neq \chi'$.

Comment: note that $\chi(g)^{-1}=\overline{\chi(g)}=\overline{\chi}(g)$ and therefore $\chi(g)^{-1}\chi'(g)=(\overline{\chi}\chi')(g)$ because $\hom(G,\mathbb C^*)$ is a group under multiplication! Now $\overline{\chi}\chi'$ is the trivial character precisely when $\chi'=\overline{\chi}^{-1}=\chi$.